# How to sequentially concatenate every nth:(nth+j) object in a list of objects

Tags: r, list, for-loop, seq

I wish to concatenate every nth:nth(+jth) object in a list of objects I have. More specifically, I would like every two objects to be concatenated.
A small sample of the list in question is below.

```
list("SRR1772151_1.fastq", "SRR1772151_2.fastq", "SRR1772152_1.fastq", 
    "SRR1772152_2.fastq", "SRR1772153_1.fastq", "SRR1772153_2.fastq")
```

I would like to make a new list from this which looks closer to this.

```
list(c("SRR1772151_1.fastq", "SRR1772151_2.fastq"), c("SRR1772152_1.fastq", 
"SRR1772152_2.fastq"), c("SRR1772153_1.fastq", "SRR1772153_2.fastq"
))
```

I have made the following attempt at doing this but my for loop has been unsuccessful.

```
for (i in seq(1,36, 2)) {
  for (j in 1:18) {
    unlist(List1[i:i+1]) -> List2[[j]]
  }
}
```

Any help or advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: `i:i` is `i`; `i:i+1` is `i+1`, eventually you want `i:(i+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide this into two problems -- split the list, e.g.,

```
elts = split(lst, 1:2)
```

and concatenate the elements

```
Map(c, elts[[1]], elts[[2]])
```

But I think it's better to follow 'tidy' data practices and to create a single vector with a grouping factor

```
df = data.frame(fastq = unlist(x), grp = 1:2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or more discriptively

```
df = data.frame(
    fastq = unlist(lst),
    sample = factor(sub("_[12].fastq", "", unlist(lst))),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

It's better to work with tidy data because one can accomplish more knowing less, for instance notice that when working with lists you have to learn about `split()` and `Map()` and `c()`, whereas working with vectors and data.frames you don't!

Comment: Or `Map(\`c\`, lst[c(TRUE, FALSE)], lst[c(FALSE, TRUE)])`

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I found both Map functions most useful for this question. The df creation was useful but I wanted to keep my objects in a list format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one other attempt using dataframes. The output is a list.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(X1 = unlist(my_list), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
  group_by(str_sub(X1,1,10)) %>% # assuming first 10 characters forms the string
  summarise(list_value=list(X1)) %>% 
  pull(list_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, you can create a vector of consecutive groups of size `j` with:

```r
ceiling(seq_along(x) / j)
```

… and then use `tapply()` to concatenate all elements in those groups. Unlike using `Map()`, this will also work if the chunk size does not equally divide the length of the list.

```r
x <- list("SRR1772151_1.fastq", "SRR1772151_2.fastq", "SRR1772152_1.fastq",
    "SRR1772152_2.fastq", "SRR1772153_1.fastq", "SRR1772153_2.fastq")

tapply(x, ceiling(seq_along(x) / 2), unlist)
#> $`1`
#> [1] "SRR1772151_1.fastq" "SRR1772151_2.fastq"
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] "SRR1772152_1.fastq" "SRR1772152_2.fastq"
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] "SRR1772153_1.fastq" "SRR1772153_2.fastq"
tapply(x, ceiling(seq_along(x) / 4), unlist)
#> $`1`
#> [1] "SRR1772151_1.fastq" "SRR1772151_2.fastq" "SRR1772152_1.fastq"
#> [4] "SRR1772152_2.fastq"
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] "SRR1772153_1.fastq" "SRR1772153_2.fastq"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>